# MySQL compare now() (only date, not time) with a datetime field

Tags: mysql

I have a `duedate` column(`datetime` format) that specifies the due date of a ticket, now i need to get 'Due today' tickets base on the comparison between `now()` with `duedate`. i.e `2010-04-29 02:00` vs `2010-04-29 10:00` would return true in this matter.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use `DATE(NOW())` to compare dates

`DATE(NOW())` will give you the date part of current date and `DATE(duedate)` will give you the date part of the due date. then you can easily compare the dates

So you can compare it like

```
DATE(NOW()) = DATE(duedate)
```

OR

```
DATE(duedate) = CURDATE()
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: @njk : yes im trying to improve. may I know why it is poor?

Comment: Showing an example would help tremendously.

Comment: Also, you can use `CURDATE()` instead of `DATE(NOW())`

Comment: Can you change it to 'Will due today' ? i.e `2010-04-29 02:00` vs `2010-04-29 10:00` would return true and `2010-04-29 12:00` vs `2010-04-29 10:00` would return false.

Comment: @user1918956 : yes add another clause using TIME() function. may be if you give me the requirement of what time range do you want?

Comment: well i simply put `AND duedate > now()` and it works, thanks again :)

Answer (score 23):

Compare date only instead of date + time (NOW) with:

```
CURDATE()
```

Comment: To make your answer more helpful and increase the chances of getting upvotes include a full query sample using the function and a link to the function's documentation.