# mysql statement (SELECT) based on date now

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to ask if my Mysql statement is correct or not.. When I run this under mysql it does not return any error but I cannot retrieve the row for it. Here's my statement:

```
SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE createddate = NOW()
```

Here's what my table looks like

[image]

Comment: do you want to search the table for today's date?

Comment: `NOW()` will give you something as `2014-05-02 19:56:14` and this becomes equal to `createddate` will be rarer than the rarest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL compare now() (only date, not time) with a datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533914/mysql-compare-now-only-date-not-time-with-a-datetime-field)

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE DATE(createddate) = DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `createddate = NOW()` is an exact time comparison , you are probably only interested in the year, month, day being the the same.

See here for details on how to do what you are trying to do:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to search for today date.
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE DATE(createddate) = DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

`now()` includes the time. Given that your fields contain date AND time values, you'll only ever get a match if the date AND time are exact matches. You need to compare dates only:

```
... WHERE DATE(createddate) = CUR_DATE()
               '2014-05-02' = '2014-05-02'
```

v.s.

```
... WHERE createddate = now()
'2014-05-02 22:14:00' = '2014-05-02 01:02:03'
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this isn't exactly what you want: NOW() function will return the exact timestamp for when the query is run, which means you are asking it for any records created at that exact moment in time.

You may want to try something more like:

```
SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE createddate = YOUR_DATE_CRITERIA
```